# I want to run a script during container run based on env variable that I pass

Tags: docker

I want to run a script during run time and not during image build.
The script runs based on env variable that I pass during container run.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch $env
```

Docker file

```
FROM busybox
ENV env parm
RUN mkdir PRATHAP
ADD apt.sh /PRATHAP
WORKDIR /PRATHAP
RUN chmod 777 apt.sh
CMD sh apt.sh
```

when I try to run: docker container run -it -e env=test.txt  sh
the script is not running

I am just getting the sh terminal. If I remove it the the container is not alive.. Please help me how to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

Your `docker run` starts `sh` which overrides your `CMD` in Dockerfile. To get around this, you need to replicate the original `CMD` via the command line.

```
$ docker run -it -e env=test.txt <image:tag> sh -c "./init.sh; sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a Docker container runs a single command, and then exits.  If you `docker run` your image without overriding the command, the only thing the container will do is `touch` a file inside the isolated container filesystem, and then it will promptly exit.

If you need to do some startup-time setup, a useful pattern is to write it into an entrypoint script.  When a container starts up, Docker runs whatever you have named as the `ENTRYPOINT`, passing the `CMD` as additional parameters (or it just runs `CMD` if there is no `ENTRYPOINT`).  You can use the special shell command `exec "$@"` to run the command.  So revisiting your script as an entrypoint script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#      ^^ busybox image doesn't have bash (nor does alpine)

# Do the first-time setup
touch "$env"

# Launch the main container process
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile set this script to be the `ENTRYPOINT`, and then whatever long-running command you actually want the container to do to be the `CMD`.

```sh
FROM busybox
WORKDIR /PRATHAP        # Also creates the directory
COPY apt.sh .           # Generally prefer COPY to ADD
RUN chmod 0755 apt.sh   # Not world-writable
ENV env parm
ENTRYPOINT ["./apt.sh"] # Must be JSON-array syntax
                        # Do not need to name interpreter, since
                        # it is executable with #! line
CMD sh                  # Or whatever the container actually does
```

Comment: This way `CMD sh` won't work in the Dockerfile as well as provided in command line, because when both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` is present, `CMD` is fed as parameters to `ENTRYPOINT`, which in this case will be ignored. by `apt.sh`. So when you set entrypoint to a script, there's no way to run another command after that script, including `sh` which is necessary to keep an interactive shell.

Comment: The `exec "$@"` line runs the `CMD`, replacing the entrypoint script.